# On using Continuity as a GUI for Perl

Tags: javascript, html, perl

I have been playing with using [Continuity](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Continuity) as a "platform-independent multiuser GUI" for Perl. However I am interested in a few things to make this usable/safe.

1. I am not aware of a "browse for folder" dialog with HTML, can this be hacked together somehow, or is my knowledge out of date.
2. Can I prevent the server that Continuity starts from being globally viewable (i.e. can I make it only accessible from `localhost`).
3. Can I make the script start a browser (probably the system default) and send it to the proper address and port once the server is set to loop? I would think this would be accomplished with `fork` except that loop doesn't return.

   Finally, perhaps someone with more clout should add a tag for `continuity` (and tag this).

Comment: The page you linked to for Continuity is a mess of spam links now.

Comment: Thats, true I have seen that and forgotten. I will change the link to the CPAN entry.

Comment: In the end, I think the problems inherent in `Continuity` make this a bad idea. I am a little more hopeful for something using [`Mojolicious`](http://mojolicio.us) but I haven't really worked on it. Therefore I am going to close this one. Eric's answer contains an excellent alternative, so I will accept that one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not related to Continuity, I have written the module [XUL::Gui](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XUL%3a%3aGui) which renders a gui in Firefox from Perl.  (it also has a cross browser [Web::Gui](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Web%3a%3aGui) mode with fewer features)  Perhaps it fits your needs.  In particular, it offers a file picker dialog (XUL::Gui only), is only accessible from localhost, and automatically launches and manages the browser window.

If you are sold on Continuity as the framework, you might be able to borrow the logic XUL::Gui uses to achieve the above features. (search for `sub filepicker`, and `sub start` in the source)

Lastly, here is an example of a simple gui for a command line app:

```
use XUL::Gui;

display Window
    title     => 'Foo Processor',
    minheight => 300,
    Hbox( MIDDLE,
        (map {
            my $id = $_;
            CheckBox
                id     => $id,
                label  => "use $id",
                option => sub {
                    shift->checked eq 'true' ? " -$id" : ()
                }
        } qw/foo bar baz/),
        Label(
            value => 'num: '
        ),
        TextBox(
            id     => 'num',
            type   => 'number',
            option => sub {' -num ' . shift->value}
        ),
        Button(
            label     => 'run',
            oncommand => sub {
                my @opts = map {ID($_)->option} qw/foo bar baz num/;

                ID(txt)->value = "fooproc @opts";
            }
        ),
    ),
    TextBox( FILL SCROLL id => 'txt', multiline => 'true' );
```

Comment: Excellent, I'll take a look. I'm not absolutely sold on Continuity, but it was the first time I had seen a web/browser package/framework that it looked like I could really build an application around. I will consider your framework and certainly look at the source! Thanks